# What is the % operator in Python's print statement called?

Tags: python

Consider:

```
print "%s is %d years old." % ('Meirav', 5)
```

What is the `%` operator between the string literal and the tuple called? Other than in the print statement, where else is it seen in Python?

Comment: I don't know how its called, but other uses for it are getting the remainder of a division, for ex. `11 % 3 == 2`.

Comment: @BrtH: That is the modulus operator. The modulus and the operator in question seem to be overrides, just like the override of the addition operator for string concatenation.

Comment: @BrtH: Actually, according to minitech's answer, they are the same operator. Interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's the modulus operator, but you asked "where else is it seen?", which is what I answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It's known as the "string formatting" or "interpolation" operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), and it's used anywhere you might want to interpolate formatted data into a string.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that using `%` for string formatting has been (somewhat) deprecated in favor of the [`str.format` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which is available in Python 2.6 and higher.